# jquery on does not react to element added by clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was under the impression that jquery's `on()` reacted to events attached elements  dynamically added to the dom (via ajax or cloning, etc). However, the following is only working for the element attached to the dom at page load. The other copy I make of it using `clone()` is not being, well, handled.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ship_via_dropdown').on('change', function () {
        console.log($(this));
        if ($(this).hasClass('prev_change')) {
            console.log('has');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('prev_change');
            console.log('hasn\'t');
        }
    });
});
```

Code for cloning:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form1 = $('.line_item_wrapper').children().clone(); 
    $('#new_line_content_1').html(form1);
});
```

HTML for dropdown (contents added by jquery db query on document ready)

```
<span class="select ship_via_select_container">
    <select class="ship_via_dropdown ship_via_dropdown_1">
    </select>
</span>
```

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: Care to share the code where you do the cloning?

Comment: @Adrian Yes! give me two seconds.

Comment: Did you read the docs? http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does, but not in the way that you think.  When used as you have used it:

```
$('.ship_via_dropdown').on('change',
```

It is really not different than using `.change()`.  What you are looking for is [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).  This takes the following form:

```
$("<selector to static ancestor>").on('change', '.ship_via_dropdown', function () {
```

Where `<selector to static ancestor>` is a selector to a static ancestor of the dynamically added elements.  (one that is not dynamically created)  As a last resort `document` can be used here.  However for performance, this should be the closest static ancestor element.

Answer (score 6):

Either delegate the event instead:

```
$(document).on('change', '.ship_via_dropdown', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    if ($(this).hasClass('prev_change')) {
        console.log('has');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('prev_change');
        console.log('hasn\'t');
    }
});
```

Or better yet, use [`.clone(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to clone with events. (Note: this will only work if you're cloning AFTER the event handler is attached.)

Comment: Note that delegating to the document isn’t always the best choice for performance, it is generally recommended to delegate to the closest common ancestor instead.

Comment: `document` should only be used where a more appropriate ancestor element is not available.

Comment: @David Yes yes, but (a) I didn't have the HTML to look at, and (b) doing it this way is rarely a performance issue in the real world anyway.

Comment: @Blazemonger I’m not saying your answer is wrong, just adding useful information.

Answer (score 2):

> jquery's `on()` reacted to events attached elements dynamically added

No - or at least, only if you [use it with delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). The [`live` method](http://api.jquery.com/live/) did always delegate events to the `document`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$('.ship_via_dropdown').on('change', function () {
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('change',".ship_via_dropdown", function () {
```

Comment: Does this need to be combined with $(document).ready in someway, or does the simple $(document) combined with on() take care of this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @thomas Yes, of course it has. I just suggested a quick substituion

Comment: I see. It seems to work without `$(document).ready()` so I was just checking. Thanks again!

Comment: @thomas You are correct that `ready` isn't needed in this case.  The handler is being attached to `document` itself so there is no need to wait for the contents of `document` to be ready.